# What is the sixth Postgres DLL?

Tags: postgresql, windows, dll

I'm trying to compile and run a C++ program on Windows 11 that uses the Postgres driver. (The operating system, database and program are all 64-bit.) For now, just a minimal test program that just calls `PQsetdbLogin`.

I've got as far as compiling with the necessary include path, linking with `libpq.lib`, and trying to run the resulting program. The first few attempts popped up error messages about  missing DLLs, as expected, so each time, I copied the mentioned DLL into the current directory where I am trying to run the program. I've got as far as copying the following five DLLs:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\lib\libpq.dll
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin\libssl-3-x64.dll
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin\libintl-9.dll
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin\libcrypto-3-x64.dll
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll
```

But now when I try to run the program, it still crashes, but now the error message is uninformative:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).

Google suggests a likely cause is that there is still a missing DLL. That for some reason is, this time, not being named? Is that the case, and if so, which DLL is it? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Visual Studio command prompt (It might be listed as “x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022”), and run `DUMPBIN /IMPORTS` on the executable.  This will display every DLL and function it requires.  Also check the dependencies of the DLLs it loads.

Wild guess: it was compiled with either Cygwin or MingW64, and needs its runtime?  I generally use Clang or ICX with `-target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`, which links to the Windows system libraries.